# Bayes' rule and probability

Tags: probability, bayesian

I've got a probability question:

Given a 5-faced die (1,2,3,4,5),call it die $A$, each face has probability as follows:

$$\begin{array}{rrrrr}
    \text{Face}    & 1  &  2     &  3  &     4  &      5 \\
    \text{Prob}    & 0.2 & 0.15  &  0.1 &  0.25  &   0.3
\end{array}$$

We roll this die three times and get $O = \{2,4,5\}$

Q1. What's the probability that we get this kind of outcome assuming that we are using die A

My solution is: $3!\cdot0.15\cdot0.25\cdot0.3$,

Q2. Given another 5-faced die $B$ and its probability distribution is as follows:

$$\begin{array}{rrrrr}
    \text{Face}    & 1  &  2     &  3  &     4  &      5 \\
    \text{Prob}    & 0.1 & 0.2  &  0.3  &  0.25  &   0.15
\end{array}$$

Now, we have 2 dice, given that we do not know which die we rolled, but the outcome is $O = \{2,4,5\}$, whats the probability this die is die A?

Comment: You need to be more specific about your second experiment. Presumably, one chooses either die $A$ or die $B$, with given probabilities, and rolls three times. Without knowing what those probabilities are, your second question is not solvable.

Comment: Note: not "Baye" ... named for Rev. Thomas Bayes.  The Baye Rule is as nonexistent as the Stoke Theorem.  Write "Bayes' Rule" or "Bayes's Rule" or something.

Comment: MAYBE HE ROLLS B AND GETS THE [2.4.5] OUTCOME WITH THREE ROLLS.  ASSUMING YOU KNOW THE MULTINOMIAL DISTRIBUTION FOR A WHAT IS THE P VALUE OF THE TEST THAT THE DIE USED IS A.  tHE NULL IS THAT IT IS A AND THE ALTERNATIVE IS NOT A.  IF THIS FORMULATION IS CORRECT THE DISTRIBUTION FOR B IS IRRELEVANT.  @LouisTan Do I have the correct interpretation?

Comment: @Michael, please stop SHOUTING.

Comment: @Loius, welcome back. Any thoughts on the answer I posted a few days ago?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Occasional capitalization for emphasis is okay I think.  I don't like to think about it as shouting.  Please try to spell Louis' name correctly.

Comment: The reason for emphasis in my question @LouisTan is that the question has no specific answer without knowing that a random mechanism is involved in picking the die and that the probability of picking A is known.  If we assume a value for the probaility that A is drawn and we know the multinomial distributions for the faces for both die A and die B then Gerry Myerson's answer applies.

Comment: @Louis, my apologies for my incorrect spelling.

Comment: @Michael, please, there is a difference between OCCASIONAL capitalization and a whole paragraph of it.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I have re-edited my question to make it more precise. So, in Q1, I am asking P(O|A).

Answer (score 2):

Probability of die A, given outcome 245, equals (probability of die A) times (probability of 245 given die A), divided by the sum of [(probability of die A) times (probability of 245 given die A)] and [(probability of die B) times (probability of 245 given die B)].

Now you have calculated probability of 245 given die A, and you can similarly calculate probability of 245 given die B, but what you need to know is the a priori probability of die A and probability of die B. Perhaps you are meant to assume that these are both 1/2.

EDIT: The above concerns Q2. I believe the solution to Q1 in the original post is correct.

Comment: +1 This seems to be a reasonable interpetation if Bayes' rule is to be appied. It assume the multinomial distributions are known and that it is not known if A or B is chosen but the decision was made by say flipping a fair coin with A chosen if say it lands heads.